# Modify any data in xml file and save the file with new changes via C++ program

Tags: c++, xml

I have a configuration file which is used to hold some data to be used on boot up. This file is in `xml` format. I am using `XPath` parsing method, in `libxml2` library to get the data and store it in some variables. My program has provision for the user to change some of these parameters and it must be saved back in the xml file. What I require is some mechanism to modify and sava back any data in the `xml` file via my program so that on reboot the new setting will be applied to the system.

I am working in `C++`..

Sample format of my xml file:

```
< parent tag>

   < child tag1>value1< /child tag>

   < child tag2>value2< child tag2>

< /parent tag>
```

Thanks for your reply, in advance...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/#xpath2.c has examples of modifying the xml file and saving it back.  This should be an easy to follow tutorial to serve your needs.